# How to equalize the weight of each item in multiple checklists?

Tags: normalization

I have 5 checklists with different perfect scores. Say, I have checklist A-E with their corresponding perfect scores:

A = 24
B = 17
C = 38
D = 41
E = 25

Each item in all the checklists are equivalent to 1 point.
I want to compare one item from one checklist to another item in other checklists.
How could I make the weight of each item in all the checklists equal to each other?

Comment: Not quite understanding.  The natural weight is 1/n for each list, e.g. 1/17 for B, 1/41 for D because each item is 1/17th (or 1/41st) of perfect.  You could achieve equal weights by combining the checklists into one big checklist with 145 items, but I somehow don't think that's what you are aiming for.  Can you write a bit more about your desired outcome?

Comment: What do you mean "compare ONE item to another item in other checklists"?  You imply that you're not comparing overall checklist scores, but the frequency of choosing (correctly?) that one item?

Answer (score 1):

Take the number of items in a checklist and consider that 100%, or 1.0. Thus, each individual item in a checklist is worth 1/n points.

For example, a 12/24 score in A would be equal to a 19/38 score in C (both 50% or 0.5), but both would be worse than an 11/17 score in B (~65% or .65).

You can then compare scores across checklists by looking at the percent, or if everyone completes all five checklists you can add their percentages and get a total answer which would be divided by the number of checklists, or in this case 5.

Seems pretty straightforward?